the program is always hang when it runs to ExportAsFixedFormat by powershell
I have a simple requirement that convert to pdf by excel. My example code is
[string]$savepath = "C:\"
[string]$dToday = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

$wb = "C:\file.xlsx"
 
# Create the Excel application object
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$objExcel.visible = $false   #Do not open individual windows
 
$workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb, 3)
$worksheet = $objExcel.worksheets.item(1) #SK

$value = $objExcel.Cells.Item(1, 6).Text
$value.Text #this should give you back the Value in that Cell
$workbook.RefreshAll()
$filepath = Join-Path -Path $savepath -ChildPath ('qqqq_{0}.pdf' -f $dtoday) 


# Give delay to save
Start-Sleep -s 5

# Save Workbook
$workbook.Saved = $true 
"saving $filepath" 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type] 
$worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath) #SK
$objExcel.Workbooks.close() 
$objExcel.Quit()

when the program print "saving C:\qqqq_20240528.pdf",it'l hang.
please how can i solve it?
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.Version

output 16.0
and I'm in docker container to run the program(office365).

I tested your program I have the same excel version as you and it all works perfectly.
